# Why does installing `parted` try and install nginx?

Tags: apt, nginx, parted

My `parted` install seems to fail with a dependency on `nginx`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install parted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libmpdec2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  parted-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  parted
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 44.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 188 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main parted amd64 2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1 [44.2 kB]
Fetched 44.2 kB in 0s (1,151 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package parted.
(Reading database ... 32465 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../parted_2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking parted (2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nginx-core (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.5) ...
Starting nginx: invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't see why `nginx` should be a requirement for `parted`. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Its not parted,but a previosly uncomplete installation.

Answer (score 2):

As nephilim said, it isn't being installed because of parted, it's finishing a previously incomplete installation because you called apt.

If you want to fix this, I'd suggest removing NGINX if you have no need for it (`apt remove nginx-core --purge`, note that purge, will remove your configuration files for it as well so only do that if you feel like it) or fixing it manually (try `dpkg --configure nginx-core` to maybe get more information but it seems that the service fails to start).

Comment: You can just remove the package (that will make it stop trying to configure it) without purging.

Comment: I know but if he doesn't need the web server, he might as well clean up its configuration. I did mention the effect of `--purge` and the fact it's optional.